# Rails: Where does the 'create' method redirects to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parsing, url-routing

I'm a complete rails beginner and I'm trying to understand the full concepts. I've literally been trying to solve this problem for hours and I wanted to ask on here.

I would like to perform a JSON request to my rails app which runs on localhost. But I do not know if I am using a wrong type of JSON request software (I'm using CocoaRestClient for mac) or my code is incorrect.

I've observed that when I create a POST type JSON request in rails it is leaded to the **create** method. And what I am trying to achieve is to actually store multiple variables that I receive from JSON and later on show it on the page. I know it's dead simple but it is really hard because I've tried a lot things.

My questions:

1. I will be capturing the event on create method. How can I get a parameter from the JSON request. I've tried `@username = params[:username]` but it didn't work out.
2. If I ever get lucky enough to capture the parameters that is provided by the JSON in which page should I print them. I've tried to show on index or show pages but couldn't manage that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `request` variable that in fact is instance of [`ActionDispatch::Request`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html) class. Here you have [`#body`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-body) method that return raw request body. So if you send JSON request in body you should parse it i.e.:

```
data = JSON.parse request.body
data['username']
```

And if you wanna display it you have 3 options:

- render view in `#create` method what is a bad idea, because this method is only to save model to DB
- save data to DB and display on next page
- or use `flash` object and store it only to next request